# Appending an image to a stack of images

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

X is 6752 x 60 x 72 which means I have 6752 images of shape 60x72. Y is of dimension 60x72!

How do I append Y to X?

Tried np.dstack, np.append, etc after reshaping but no luck so far!

Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this:

```
Y = Y.reshape((1,60,72))
X = np.concatenate((X,Y))
```

Comment: Thank you I believe its `X = np.concatenate((X,Y))`. This fixed my issue.

Comment: You're right.  That's what I get for retyping instead of copy/paste.